# R Combining several graphs (subcategory) in one with same scale using ggplot2 / facetting

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several data with categories (A, B, C) and subcategories (A01, B01, B02, ...). I want to have in one unique graph the subcategories facetted by category (sharing the same scale).

Here is an example of my workflow :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)

# Create data
subcategory <- c("A01", "A02", "A03", "B01", "B02", "C01", "C02", "D01")
qty <- c(4, 5, 3, 8, 4, 2, 1, 6)
df <- data.frame(subcategory=subcategory, qty=qty)
df$category <- factor(str_extract(df$subcategory, "[A-Z]"))

# Data aggregation
df.ply <- ddply(df, .(subcategory, category), summarize, qty=sum(qty))

# Plotting
plot <- ggplot(df.ply, aes(x=subcategory, y=qty, fill=category))
plot + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(category~.)
```

So this aggregated table :

```
    subcategory category    qty
1   A01         A           4
2   A02         A           5
3   A03         A           3
4   B01         B           8
5   B02         B           4
6   C01         C           2
7   C02         C           1
8   D01         D           6
```

Gives me this picture:

[image]

... I would like to have only the corresponding subcategories in each facet (remove the empty ones). Is this possible with ggplot2 ?

Should I use viewports and subplots instead of facetting? I'm quite lost about how to adapt the instructions p146 of Hadley Wickam's book for ggplot2 in my usercase...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the last line of your code in:

```
plot + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~category, scales="free")
```

[image]

You can still use `facet_grid`:

```
plot + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_grid(~category, scales="free")
```

but with `facet_wrap` makes you choose nrow and ncol of the facets as well.